# Rowspan not expanding

Tags: html, html-table

I made a table in html but when I try to increase the height of a table cell it doesn't increase.

this is the `index.html` file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--Begin-->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato: 100,300,400,700|Luckiest+Guy|Oxygen:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Cards</h1>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Card</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">1</td>
        <td>Charizard</td>
        <!--<td><img src="https://52f4e29a8321344e30ae-0f55c9129972ac85d6b1f4e703468e6b.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/products/pictures/1105091.jpg">Charizard card</img></td>-->
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is the `style.css` file:

```css
table {
  height: 40%;
  left: 10%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: static;
  width: 80%;
}

thead th {
  background: #88CCF1;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

tr {
  background: #f4f7f8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

th, td {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 33.3333%;
}
```

This is how that looks:

[image: a busy cat]

But that isnt what I wanted because in the code I put `rowspan="2"` so here is an example of what I expected

[image: nothging]

But why is it that the first image is the result of this code and not the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a third row in your HTML code, that's why that cell doesn't span into a third row. As soon as you add a third row, the rowspan will look as expected:

```css
table {
  height: 40%;
  left: 10%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: static;
  width: 80%;
}

thead th {
  background: #88CCF1;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

tr {
  background: #f4f7f8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

th, td {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 33.3333%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato: 100,300,400,700|Luckiest+Guy|Oxygen:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Cards</h1>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Card</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">1</td>
        <td>Charizard</td>
        <!--<td><img src="https://52f4e29a8321344e30ae-0f55c9129972ac85d6b1f4e703468e6b.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/products/pictures/1105091.jpg">Charizard card</img></td>-->
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 3, second cell</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```